# Jquery append not sequentially adding div's when run from function

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

What I am trying to do is keep appending divs to `#ajax_tweets` when my ajax request returns a success. What currently happens is each time the ajax function is run on a timer and the ajax return a success the desired latest div is shown on screen correctly. However when it runs the next time the previous div is overwritten and not appended too. Either I am appending incorrectly, or I am not sure.. being driving me crazy for a while now.

Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(ajax_test, 10000);
    counter = 0;

    function ajax_test() {
        $(".tweets").html('Retrieving...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/get_latest_tweets.php",
            data: "tid=" + id,
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg != "") {
                    add_to_tweet_feed( msg );
                    id++;
                    alert(id + msg);
                }     
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(".tweets").html('Timeout contacting server..');
            }
        });
    }

    function add_to_tweet_feed ( msg ) {
        $("#ajax_tweets").append(msg);  
    }
});
```

Code returned from server:

```
<div id="'.$tid.'" class="t_feed">             
                               <div class="calander right">
                                <div class="calander_month"><span>'.$row['pub_month'].'</span></div>
                                <div class="calander_day"><span>'.$row['pub_day'].'</span> </div> 
                               </div>
                                <span class="ajax_tweet bold">'.$row['source'].'</span>
                                <p>'.$tweet.'</p>
                              </div><div class="clear_both></div>
```

Front end code:

```
           <div id="ajax_tweets" class="tweets">

           </div>
```

Comment: I really wish somebody would fix the SO markdown code so that tabs would just be converted to spaces :-(

Comment: So what is the element called "ajax_tweets"?  Another `<div>`? Also exactly what does your server return as "msg"?  Is it just plain tweet text, or is there markup around it?

Comment: actually tabs work out nicely if you use them consistently and correctly

Comment: @emmett thanks you beat me to it

Comment: Do you have the 'tweets' class on your element with id 'ajax_tweets'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your code actually clears out your whole container, that's why you only have the last one in there:

```
$(".tweets").html('Retrieving...');
```

One solution could be to make your markup something like this:

```
<div id="ajax_tweets" class="tweets">
    <div id="ajax_message"></div>
</div>
```

...and change your code to update that element and insert new tweets in front of it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(ajax_test, 10000);
    counter = 0;

    var $message = $("#ajax_message");

    function ajax_test() {
        $message.html('Retrieving...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/get_latest_tweets.php",
            data: "tid=" + id,
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function(msg) {
                $message.html('');
                if (msg != "") {
                    add_to_tweet_feed( msg );
                    id++;
                }     
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $message.html('Timeout contacting server..');
            }
        });
    }

    function add_to_tweet_feed ( msg ) {
        $(msg).insertBefore($message);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** Fixed a bug in the above code (bad usage of `insertBefore()`). Also, in case you're worried about the order in which your requests come back, you can add placeholders and replace them on success or remove them on failure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(ajax_test, 10000);
    counter = 0;

    var $message = $("#ajax_message");

    function ajax_test() {
        $message.html('Retrieving...');

        var $placeholder = $('<div></div>').insertBefore($message).hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/get_latest_tweets.php",
            data: "tid=" + id,
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function(msg) {
                $message.html('');
                if (msg != "") {
                    add_to_tweet_feed(msg, $placeholder);
                    id++;
                }     
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $placeholder.remove();
                $message.html('Timeout contacting server..');
            }
        });
    }

    function add_to_tweet_feed (msg, $placeholder) {
        $placeholder.show().replaceWith(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: So I can't use append thats the problem?

Comment: No, the real problem was that you used the same container for messages as well, effectively clearing it down before every request.

Comment: You can move my message div out of the content if you want and just keep using append.